# Tomcat JMX/RMI: How server interface is chosen?

Tags: java, tomcat, rmi, jmx

I enable JMX server and JMX Registry in Tomcat using

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"
      rmiRegistryPortPlatform="10001" rmiServerPortPlatform="10002" />
```

Client connects to 10001 and Tomcat returns its address and port 10002, right?
But if I have several addresses on the interface Tomcat returns the first one.

- Is this a tomcat or RMI issue?
- How can I set interface and/or IP address to be returned to the client?
- Is it possible to use JMX directly over the one TCP port with out of all that RMI stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you question: you should specify `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` as outlined in the answer [Tomcat 6, JMX and the dynamic port problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345752/tomcat-6-jmx-and-the-dynamic-port-problem/6356940#6356940)

As an answer how to configure direct access: specify the JMX remote port as outlined in [Monitoring and Managing Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html):

```
    set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=%my.jmx.port%
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

As far as understand, the calls are still done as RMI calls.