# java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2 remote reference in stub

Tags: java, ubuntu, jmx, jconsole

I am trying to connect to a remote Java process which is running on a different machine using JConsole tool on my Ubuntu machine.

This is how I am running the Java program in remote machine:

> sudo java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=51082
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -jar myfile.jar

I am running JConsole command on my machine like this:

> jconsole -debug -J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=Logging.properties

This is my `Logging.properties` file:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

sun.rmi.level=FINEST
.level = INFO

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = \

java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

// Use FINER or FINEST for javax.management.remote.level - FINEST is

// very verbose...

javax.management.level = FINEST

javax.management.remote.level = FINER
```

Now on my Jconsle UI I have given below properties:

[image]

When I click on `Connect` button I am getting exception saying:

```
    FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://my-remote-host:51082/jmxrmi] failed to connect: java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2 remote reference in stub!
    java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2 remote reference in stub!

This is the complete stacktrace of the exception as per logs:

Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM RMIConnector connect
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://my-remote-host:51082/jmxrmi] connecting...
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM RMIConnector connect
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://my-remote-host:51082/jmxrmi] finding stub...
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint <clinit>
FINE: VMPanel.connect: localHostKnown = true, localHost = 127.0.0.8
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef newCall
FINE: VMPanel.connect: get connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport <init>
FINE: VMPanel.connect: Version = 2, ep = [127.0.0.8:0]
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint getLocalEndpoint
FINE: VMPanel.connect: created local endpoint for socket factory null on port 0
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel createConnection
FINE: VMPanel.connect: create connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint newSocket
FINER: VMPanel.connect: opening socket to [my-remote-host:51082]
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:55 PM sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory createSocket
FINE: VMPanel.connect: host: my-remote-host, port: 51082
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:58 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel createConnection
FINER: VMPanel.connect: server suggested 10.56.36.2:36585
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:58 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel createConnection
FINER: VMPanel.connect: using 127.0.0.8:0
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:58 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef newCall
FINER: VMPanel.connect: create call context
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:58 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef logClientCall
FINER: VMPanel.connect: outbound call: [endpoint:[my-remote-host:51082](remote),objID:[0:0:0, 0]] : sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(java.lang.String)
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:58 PM sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall <init>
FINER: VMPanel.connect: write remote call header...
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:58 PM sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall getOutputStream
FINER: VMPanel.connect: getting output stream
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:58 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef invoke
FINER: VMPanel.connect: execute call
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall getInputStream
FINER: VMPanel.connect: getting input stream
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass
FINE: VMPanel.connect: name = "javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@530f243b
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass
FINER: VMPanel.connect: class "javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub" found via defaultLoader, defined by null
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass
FINE: VMPanel.connect: name = "java.rmi.server.RemoteStub", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@530f243b
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass
FINER: VMPanel.connect: class "java.rmi.server.RemoteStub" found via defaultLoader, defined by null
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass
FINE: VMPanel.connect: name = "java.rmi.server.RemoteObject", codebase = "", defaultLoader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@530f243b
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass
FINER: VMPanel.connect: class "java.rmi.server.RemoteObject" found via defaultLoader, defined by null
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef done
FINE: VMPanel.connect: free connection (reuse = true)
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel free
FINE: VMPanel.connect: reuse connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel free
FINE: VMPanel.connect: create reaper
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef newCall
FINE: VMPanel.connect: get connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel createConnection
FINE: VMPanel.connect: create connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint newSocket
FINER: VMPanel.connect: opening socket to [127.0.1.1:57675]
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory createSocket
FINE: VMPanel.connect: host: 127.0.1.1, port: 57675
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef newCall
FINE: RMI RenewClean-[127.0.1.1:57675]: get connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel createConnection
FINE: RMI RenewClean-[127.0.1.1:57675]: create connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint newSocket
FINER: RMI RenewClean-[127.0.1.1:57675]: opening socket to [127.0.1.1:57675]
Jul 14, 2015 7:39:59 PM sun.rmi.transport.WeakRef pin
FINER: VMPanel.connect: strongRef = sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl@63a1b509
Jul 14, 2015 7:40:00 PM sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory createSocket
FINE: RMI RenewClean-[127.0.1.1:57675]: host: 127.0.1.1, port: 57675
Jul 14, 2015 7:40:00 PM sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable putTarget
FINER: VMPanel.connect: add object [0:0:0, 2]
Jul 14, 2015 7:40:00 PM sun.rmi.transport.ConnectionInputStream done
FINER: VMPanel.connect: send ack
Jul 14, 2015 7:40:00 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel newConnection
FINE: VMPanel.connect: reuse connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:40:00 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel free
FINE: VMPanel.connect: reuse connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:40:00 PM RMIConnector connect
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://my-remote-host:51082/jmxrmi] failed to connect: java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2 remote reference in stub!
java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2 remote reference in stub!
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.checkStub(RMIConnector.java:1871)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:295)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:357)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:292)
Jul 14, 2015 7:40:01 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef newCall
FINE: RMI RenewClean-[127.0.1.1:57675]: get connection
Jul 14, 2015 7:40:01 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel createConnection
```

I am not able to figure out where is the issue.

**update:**

I am able to connect to my remote host for the given port:

```
telnet my_remote_host 51082
```

As per [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/769541/is-it-possible-to-ping-an-addressport), I got the response from the host without any issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java jconsole jmx connection failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734981/java-jconsole-jmx-connection-failure)

Comment: @durron597, the error details given by OP is different in that post compared to the one that I am getting

Answer (score 9):

Please use below settings . I was also facing same issue but resolved after having below settings

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9704 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.18.137.35 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=970
```

Please note of `Djava.rmi.server.hostname` and `Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port`.

Even after this settings it will ask for insecure connection please accept it and then you are able to connect (it will give you error and of `failed to connect: java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef2 remote reference in stub!`).

Comment: OMG thank you! This was the only way I've been able to get it to work, despite multiple other sources suggesting "localhost" should work. (I'm doing it through a socks tunnel).

Comment: For me the trick was adding the hostname.