# Connection failed:Retry? Jconsole

Tags: tomcat, jconsole

I am unable to connect to jconsole in mac using localhost:9999 it says Secure    connection failed. Retry insecurely? But when i select insecure connection. It    says connection failed:retry?.

```
Added following in bash_profile and setenv.sh of tomcat 8.
-export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.102.15.224"
```

It says same thing for local processes also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMX is using 2 ports one for registry that you specifies and the other for actual connection that is randomly selected.

You can either set it [manually](http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_through_firewall_using_jmx) or let [Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345752/tomcat-6-jmx-and-the-dynamic-port-problem) to set it for you

Comment: But i am getting same problems for local processes. I mean for mbeans which are registered programmatically(which are not tomcat processes).

Comment: have you checked https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_through_firewall_using_jmx that I linked to my answer?

Comment: Sorry i will check that. On a sider note: But i am able to access and see some processes using localhost:0000.