# Error running 'Tomcat': Address localhost:1099 is already in use. Why?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm getting this error : `Error running 'Tomcat': Address localhost:1099 is already in use`

Screenshot from Intellj IDEA :

[image]

I tried to solve it by looking at the postings people posted in the face of a problem similar to mine, but I think it's a different matter from mine.

Once in my situation, there is no 'process using 1099 port'.

There is no return value when I type `netstat -aon | find "1099"` on cmd.
I've shut down the whole IntelliJ process and rebooted PC.
 I don't seem to use port 1099 at all, but there's an error like that.

Comment: Have you tried running Tomcat on a different port?

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker There are no other programs that use port 8080. the port on oracle has been changed to another port. For your information, this problem appears after formatting PC.

Comment: Your tomcat is perhaps starting more than one java process, and they try to use the same port?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I checked the port with ```netstat -aon```. It doesn't seem like there's any other process to use 8080 port, but can i check it out in any other way?

Comment: No, since in that case the conflict is only there when Tomcat starts.  Any logs?  What's this about the 8080 port??  Isn't it the 1099 any longer?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille 8080 port is used only in Tomcat. There is no other log. Only that message appears in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the current port number to some other port in `server.xml` of tomcat.

For example : change it to 1100.

```
<Connector port="1100" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Restart the server.

Comment: 1099 is JMX port.

Comment: Try with 1099 in the server.xml. What is happening tell me ?

Comment: What if the port '1100' is already used like the question above. Constantly changing port?

Comment: @HarryCoder Exactly, you have to do it. If some process are running on that port, then you have to change otherwise not.

Comment: @AnishB same error appears. ```Error running 'Tomcat 9.0.30': Address localhost:1099 is already in use```

Comment: @konyonuku Then, give some other port. May be some process is running which you are unaware of.

Comment: @AnishB I've never had such an error in the last few months while learning to develop a web application. 1099 is the JMX port and the port you mentioned is Tomcat's port able to change through <connector> tag in server.xml. Regardless of changing the Tomcat port through server.xml, there is an error about 1099 port.

Comment: @konyonuku Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345752/tomcat-6-jmx-and-the-dynamic-port-problem

Comment: @AnishB thank you for your comments. I'll try that :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not good at English, but I'll do my best to translate at google
I was meet that problem and I was solve that problem at 2021-01-10.
U use netstat command in window OS right?? If you are having this problem on Windows OS
Find the Hyper-V program and disable it. because Port 1099 is referred to as a program reserved for MS Hyper-V. So, if you use the hyper-v program let's find hyper-v program and make shut off. It will be a tomcat start

if u don't know how to disable hyper-v program i give MS link for u

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v#enable-the-hyper-v-role-through-settings

have a nice study?? or Develope

Answer (score 0):

Something is using that port and you need to kill the process that's using that port. You can try to go to your Task Manager and find the process that runs TomcatServer and kill it and as far as I know, there should also be a Tomcat Manager that let's you kill the current process.