# Intelij IDEA Error runing 'Tomcat 8.5.68" address 1099 is already in use

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, tomcat8

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fma7D.png)
I tried before [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986910/intellij-idea-address-localhost1099-is-already-in-use/55788410)[link 2](https://developpaper.com/question/ideatomact-address-localhost1099-is-already-in-use/) [link 4](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/debugging-in-intellij-gives-address-localhost1099-is-already-in-use-error) and Clear idea cache.
There is no error when deleting tomcat.
netstat -ano did not find 1099
I have run the code without any problems, this problem is sometimes sometimes not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error running 'Tomcat': Address localhost:1099 is already in use. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466736/error-running-tomcat-address-localhost1099-is-already-in-use-why)

Comment: I have tried to modify the port number, but whichever I change to is occupied,And mine is spring

Comment: Try restarting server.

Comment: I did not install tomcat and did not set up javahome
I have restarted the computer several times

Comment: Tomcat does not set environment variables, directly use the idea in

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in idea

You can try the following:
Run cmd as an administrator
netsh winsock reset
Then restart the computer

Hope your problem can be solved

Comment: Thank you, I used the administrator to reset and restart, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, but I don't know what to do next time.
I reinstalled jdk IDEA tomcat and it didn't work. I also reset the network, but it didn't work. After a while, I changed a project and it didn't work, but I changed it back and it was fine.

**My solution is as follows:**

- Open powershell with administrator privileges
- `netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384`
- `netsh int ipv6 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384`
- `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp`

Additional references:

[WSL2, Hyper-V & Reserved Ports](https://hungyi.net/posts/wsl2-reserved-ports/)

[Unable to bind ports: Docker-for-Windows & Hyper-V excluding but not using important port ranges
#3171](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-554587817)

[The default dynamic port range for TCP/IP has changed since Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang)

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, you should post it as a comment.